# RabbitMQ and Node.js converting message buffer to JSON

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a node.js app that connects to RabbitMQ to receive messages. When the messages come in and I output them to the console I get:
**{ data: <Buffer 62 6c 61 68>, contentType: undefined }**

How do I get a proper JSON or string out of this? Here is my example:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({ host: 'localhost' });

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});

connection.on('ready', function () {
    // Use the default 'amq.topic' exchange
    connection.queue('my-queue', function(q){   
        q.bind('#');

        q.subscribe(function (message) {                
            console.log(message);
        });
    });
});
```

The messages are being sent using the RabbitMQ management console (for testing purposes currently). In this example I sent a simple message with the topic of "test" and the body "blah".

I'm new to Node.js but I have tried to do

```
console.log(message.toJSON());
```

and I get nothing. Not even an error message. (not sure how to catch the issue)

```
console.log(message.toString());
```

When I do this I get [object Object] which doesn't help

```
console.log(JSON.parse(message.toString('utf8')));
```

Also does nothing and I get no error message. I assuming it's failing but why I don't get an exception is unknown to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me. Leaving this up in case someone else has the same issue, but the solution was:

```
console.log(message.data.toString('utf8'));
```

I was getting the object and trying to convert it all and not the data property.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using **amqplib** then the below code solves the issue.

In the **sender.js** file i convert **data** to JSON string

```
var data = [{
   name: '********',
   company: 'JP Morgan',
   designation: 'Senior Application Engineer'
}];

ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

And in the **receiver.js** i use the below code to print the content from the queue. Here i parse the **msg.content** to JSON format.

```
ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
   console.log(" [x] Received");
   console.log(JSON.parse(msg.content));
}, {noAck: true});
```

Comment: Good idea to "stringify" and then "parse" it by the consumer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: you might want to use ```Buffer.from()``` instead of ```new Buffer()``` as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj=JSON.parse( msg.content.toString())
console.log(obj.name);
```

Consider the data as

```
var details={'name':'Stack','Age':18}
```